# Suggest me to get this requirement

Tags: android, android-widget

I have to develop a app with footer having functionality highlighted in below image. I don't know that effect name. So, I'm unable to google it. Please help me to achieve my requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ViewPager (with Android Support Library you can use ViewPager on Android 1.6+), you can use [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

Answer (score -1):

You Use Gallery Widget in Android to get that feature. Create background resource to fill the box when it is selected and in normal rectangular boxes with no fill. I hope this should work for you. don't forget to limit the Gallery height so that it will be fixed.